# Android: layout alignment on different screen sizes

Tags: android, button, layout, android-relativelayout

I have created a button and edittext on a relative layout. I centered align the objects I've made on a nexus S screen but it doesn't look as I intended it to be on other screen sizes.

This is my code and an image link http://flic.kr/p/fuYgdf I dont have 10 reputation points to post images:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:background= "@drawable/chalk"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="login"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:background = "@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/password"
        android:background = "@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
    android:layout_weight="10.04"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="username"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

So basically, I want to make them center aligned in any screen. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to make them Center only???

Comment: yes Sir @ArmaanStranger I want the layout to be centered for all screen sizes have you seen the image? Please help me how can i do it? Thank you!

Comment: In my opinion for a screen like this, use LinearLayout. It will be much easier. But if you want to stick with RelativeLayout, don't align each others left or right. Use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" for each child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this::

I have used this code in my app and its working great.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Sir @Armaan Stranger I've tried it! It is centered but the button and the edittext are to small for a screen size like nexus 10 look at this http://flic.kr/p/fvwy2J

Comment: You can't make that as per screen. i think you need to change layout params of controls when there is big screen. so i think check it when app loads and set layout params programatically.

Comment: you should create different layout for large screens. this link will help you on this.. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
 android:background= "@drawable/chalk"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="login"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background = "@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background = "@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="username"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sir @Hari your code worked thank you but I noticed that the edittext and buttons are to small in a screen size like nexus 10 which is huge.. how can i make it fit the huge screen size of a nexus 10?

Comment: even in those screens it will have desirable amount of height. So, you no need to worry much about it!

Comment: check for width and height of edittext and buttons, if you have mentioned some size, changed it to WRAP_CONTENT. i guess this is your solution.